# Passing dynamic value to function parameter using Angular 1 Interpolation

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a function where I change the text of button based on some value

```
$scope.text = 'Wait';

if(Number($scope.x) == Number($scope.y))
    $scope.text = 'Go'
else if(Number($scope.x) < Number($scope.y)
    $scope.text = 'Wait'
```

I then use the `text` in the HTML on the button tag

```
<button type="submit" ng-click="proceed()">{{text}}</button>
```

Either the text, `proceed` function on the button is happening. I wanted to stop calling the `proceed` function if the text is **Wait**. To do that, I tried something like this.

```
$scope.check = function(val) {
    if(val == 'Go') {
        $scope.proceed();
    }
}
```

And I use it in the HTML like

```
<button type="submit" ng-click="check({{text}})">{{text}}</button>
```

But I get a error stating

```
Error: [$parse:syntax]
```

I wanted to if there's any other better way of doing it. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont pass text like this .

change it to :

```
<button type="submit" ng-click="check(text)">{{text}}</button>
```

This will solve your error.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to interpolate text at that point, you can just pass it to the function. 
I.E:

`<button type="submit" ng-click="check(text)">{{text}}</button>`